# Override ModelViewSet's queryset with filter backends applied

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to take into account `MyModelViewSet`'s `filter_backends` when creating custom queryset?

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (CustomFilter, )
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # It should not return all objects, but only results from `CustomFilter`
        queryset = LedgerEntry.objects.all()
        # some extra filtering
        return queryset
```

How should I implement this?

**Django**: 1.10

**Django Rest Framework**: 3.4.6

Comment: @e4c5 So by that you mean, I have to copy all of the filtering I already have in my `CustomFilter` if I want to use it in `get_queryset()`?

Comment: sorry wasn't paying close attention. you are taking about something beyond over riding the `filter_backends` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. Just extend `filter_queryset` method of ViewSet

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (CustomFilter, )
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        # super needs to be called to filter backends to be applied
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        # some extra filtering
        return queryset
```

In action methods in ViewSet it actually does this

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

So your queryset that is sent to serializer is the one that created by `get_queryset` and then filtered with `filter_queryset`